# I-beam pointer background color inversion

Tags: interface

The background color of the I-beam cursor inverted as follows (only in Blender):
[image: I-beam background inversion]
Seems that something got toggled…

N.B. Loading the factory settings couldn't solve the problem.

Specs: blender 2.79b - f4dc9f9 // MacOS 10.13.6

Thanks in advance for your suggestions!

Following: User Preferences > Themes
[image: screenshot01]
[image: screenshot02]
[image: screenshot03]
[image: screenshot04]
[image: screenshot05]

Extra:
[image: i-beam2]

Comment: try File -> Load Factory Settings

Comment: Already tried without results (question updated)

Comment: @mononym is in windows or linux ? can you include a full screenshot of your User settings in ***user Preferences*** [ctrl+alt+U], in the themes tab,

Comment: I'm on MacOS 10.13.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround solution here: https://developer.blender.org/T53648
posted by Robert Clark on May 19 2018.

In the macOS System Preferences > Accesibility > Display > Cursors size: 
…enlarge the cursor size for a tiny bit, and the bug disapears from the Blender interface.

Following the duscission on developer.blender.org, it seems that the problem is related to macOS and not to Blender.

Answer (score 0):

It should be this setting, in the "user interface" section:

[image]

Comment: The setting works fine. But when passing with the cursor over text fields, the colors are inverted. (See last image)